# How to cook the eggplant in trader joe's eggplant roll style?

Tags: vegetables, eggplant

I want to learn how to make similar style eggplant roll. I cook eggplant many times, but I have no clue how to make the eggplant moist but not wet. I see the eggplant in trader joe's eggplant roll, it is exactly what I want. Should I bake the eggplant?

Comment: I guess this is eggplant wrapped around something, and you're trying to get a good texture for that? If not, can you describe what you're getting at Trader Joe's, or even provide a picture?

Comment: I've had marinated eggplant that was soft enough to fold, but still firm enough to hold a filling ... I have no idea if that's what Trader Joe does, though.

Answer (score 1):

We have used this recipe as a template for eggplant wrap type dishes.

In this recipe example they use a grill but you can also use a rack inside the oven either baking or broiling:

> PREAHT a stovetop grill pan or outdoor grill over high heat.
>
> CUT the eggplants lengthwise into 1/4-inch thick slices (about 6 slices each eggplant).
>
> BRUSH the eggplant slices evenly with olive oil on both sides.
>
> GRILL the eggplant slices in batches for 3 minutes each side.
>
> ALLOW to cool slightly

http://mediterrasian.com/delicious_recipes_eggplant_rolls.htm

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to draw out moisture from sliced eggplant before cooking - [sweating and draining.](http://peckthebeak.com/2011/10/secret-to-tasty-eggplant-sweating-and-draining/)

This isn't like sweating vegetables over heat - you salt both sides, and place between layers of paper towels for an hour or two. This will draw out the excess moisture while seasoning the eggplant - your roll will be less watery and less bitter.